# accessing loop variable within a loop

Tags: bash

```
List = 1 2 3 4 5
for i in $LIST
do
sum=`expr $l_$i + $b`
done
```

here `l_1`, `l_2`, `l_3`, `l_4` and `l_5` are variables having some values.
when I am trying to access those values within the for loop using loop variable `i`, the value of i is getting substituted in the expression i.e the statement `(1 + $b)` is getting executed instead of `($l_1 + $b)`. I have tried various combinations of `$` symbol and also used paranthesis but nothing seems to be working.
Please help!!

Comment: `List = 1 2 3 4 5` calls the command `List` with 6 arguments, `=` being the first of them.

Comment: Bash is case sensitive. `$List` and `$LIST` are two different variables.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using l_i or list as strings, use arrays:

```
#! /bin/bash
b=11
l=(12 24 46 68 92)
for i in "${l[@]}" ; do
     ((sum=i+b))
     echo $sum
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods if you want to maintain your given example:

1. using eval: `eval expr \${L_$i} + $b`
2. using a reference variable: `REF=L_$i; expr ${!REF} + $b;`

As choroba mentioned `bash` is case sensitive so please be careful with your variable names.

Comment: I added the script because I felt it would be more helpful, but your answer is pretty thorough.

Comment: There is another option. Reference variables aren't even an option in many shells. Simple POSIX arithmetic substitution will evaluate all expansions in an expression *before* doing any math - that's the specified behavior. And so if `x=v v=20 i=$((10+$x))` is run, `$i` will equal *30*. There's an answer here which demonstrates this given the example code. And your `eval`, by the way, is dangerous. Not because `eval` is evil or any of that nonsense - it's because you're not protecting the order of expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
l_1=10 l_2=20 l_3=30 l_4=40 l_5=50
b=100
for i  in    1 2 3 4 5
do     echo "$((sum=l_$i+b))"
done
```

The value of `$sum` is set above in the current shell - it can be expanded or modified in the normal way. This occurs without the subshell/pipe overhead necessary for invoking/forking `expr` and its parent shell for each iteration.

OUTPUT:

```
110
120
130
140
150
```

Or, if you really want to use `expr`:

```
for i  in  1 2 3 4 5
do     sum=`expr "$((l_$i))" + "$b"`
       echo "$sum"
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
110
120
130
140
150
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no bash expert but here's what I came up with

```
#!/bin/bash
 b=1
 l_1=1
 l_2=2
 l_3=3
 for i in '$l_'{1,2,3}
 do
   eval dvar="${i}"
   sum=$(($dvar + $b))
 done
```

The ***i*** variable of the for loop will be initialized as '$l_1', '$l_2', and so on. Calling eval will then evaluate the value of ***i*** into ***dvar*** which then can be used in an arithmetic expression.